# Do you know another word for the most commonly used?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

I'm presenting many histograms that show the *most commonly used* cars, then the *most commony used* refrigerators, and the *most commonly used* shoes. The problem is that I don't want to repeat the expression "most commonly used".

Do you have other expressions? Thanks!

Comment: the most popular/the most sought-after/the most desired, etc.

Comment: @Rathony   the most popular sounds good. Thanks! But "the most sought-after/the most desired" doesn't represent the idead behind the histrograms. Do you know another one?

Comment: the most preferred/the most attractive

Comment: I should think **ubiquitous** would qualify as well.

Comment: I think ubiquitous/widespread etc. while they could be applicable, they aren't exactly what the OP is asking for. "*Most* common" is a relative term, it doesn't necessarily infer an *absolute* "common"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may refer to the **most widespread** products.

> Widespread definition: found or distributed over a large area or
> number of people; distributed, circulated, or occurring
> over a wide area or extent; widely diffused;
>
> Examples: The most widespread, free statistics programme is Google Analytics. Ford Australia is perhaps one of the most widespread car brands in Australia.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at ***[predominant](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/predominant)***:

> "Present as the strongest or *main* element"

and its (many) synonyms ...

Also the statistical  [***mode***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/modal):

> "Relating to a value that occurs *most frequently* in a given set of data"

Answer (score 1):

**prevalent**? **most popular**? *most widespread*? *most common*?

Answer (score 0):

**The most widely used** is a pretty commonly used expression.

> [**Ngram**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the+most+commonly+used%2Cthe+most+widely+used&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20most%20commonly%20used%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20most%20widely%20used%3B%2Cc0)

Alternately, single-word **prevailing** could fit the context just as well.

> prevailing: applies to what is most common or frequent at a certain time or in a certain place. ([**American Heritage Dictionary**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prevailing))

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers here are accurate, I cant help but think that this kind of phrasing is wrong for a histogram in general.

Typically the data is described simply as "Shoe Purchases by Type" or "Car Purchases by Model", and the histogram consumer is left to interpret the relative frequency of the purchases.

If the data is a subset then describe the subset in more detail, such as "Top 10 Shoe Purchases by Type".